# DB2 Single export file with different fixed length record formats

Tags: db2, export, fixed-length-record

I need a header/detail file exported from DB2.  All fields are fixed length human readable text.  A record is made up of a header part and a variable length detail part.  the header part has 15 fields.  Each different detail part has its own number of fields from say 5 to 30.  There are up to 50 different types of detail parts and only one header part.  The files are laid out starting with a header part followed by n detail parts.  That is considered one record.  The file could have 1..100 million records.

Right now, the data is stored in a database with a single header table and 50 different detail tables.

So is there a simple SQL way to do something like this? Here is a visualization of the arrangement of the records and parts, not the way the records would look though (they are just fixed length field text):

```
HEADER REC, type = 1
DETAIL type 1
DETAIL type 1
...
HEADER REC, type = 27
DETAIL type 27
...
```

I want to conceptually do a SELECT * FROM HEADER and then interleave that with SELECT * FROM DEATAIL.  I don't want to join HEADER to DETAIL and DETAIL is actually 50 different DETAIL tables.  Where HEADER.type -> DetailTableName.

Answer (score 0):

What platform and version of DB2?

SQL doesn't really support what you are trying to do.  In fact, you'd be hard pressed to get more anti-SQL.

Best you could do would be something like so;

```
select rectype, HFLD1 concat HFLD2 <...> as DTA from HDR
UNION ALL
SELECT rectype, DFLD1 concat DFLD2 <...> as DTA from DTL1
UNION ALL
<....>
ORDER BY rectype
```

If you happen to be using DB2 for IBM i (aka AS/400) you could look at using DDS to create a multi-format logical file.  Using EDTCDE or EDTWRD you could re-define numeric fields into character.  I think you could simply FTP the resulting LF and get the data in the format you need.

It's been a long time I've had to create such a file, it's very old school.  Back then, I'd simply use RPG to create a PF file with a single large character field.

Today, I'd send header/detail in separate exports.  As a bonus, the import would be easier too.

Comment: Not sure the version.  Probably 5 years out of date.

Comment: Would DBX and typed hierarchy be able to do this?